# Apache Hive not giving an output

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am using windows 7 64 bit.
I installed hadoop (followed the tutorial of apache).
Hadoop is working fine, I'm not getting errors in lunching it.

Then I installed Apache Hive.
When I run Hive I got 1 error saying: could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe.
I read about the error and found that it is not an issue.

However, when writing anything in Hive, I don't get an output. I tried:

```
 Hive>CREATE TABLE table1;

     SHOW TABLES;
```

Nothing happens.

Any idea what should I do, or how can I search for this problem?

Thank you

Comment: Did you create any tables?

Comment: CREATE TABLE table1 should create a table right? @eliasah

Comment: Try this : hive> `CREATE TABLE x (a INT);`
If it says Ok then your table has been created, otherwise it will give a error

Comment: I tried     CREATE TABLE x (a INT); but still nothing happens. I didn't give an error nor said OK @eliasah

Comment: Then check the hive log file. If you don't know where it is, read [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GettingStarted#GettingStarted-ErrorLogs)

Comment: Okay Thank you I will read it

Comment: Just to be sure, how have you installed hive ? Did you follow the procedure in this link (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GettingStarted ) with cygwin ?

Comment: hive-site.xml not found on CLASSPATH, this is what i found in my logs

Comment: Yes I followed the tutorial and installed it using cygwin64 @fxm

Comment: @user3782579 because you have to set your hive-site.xml. I believe the link I gave you might help you if you read it

Comment: I will read it. Thank you very much @eliasah

Comment: I am facing difficulties in making hive-site.xml, can you please give me a screenshot of how it should be? @eliasah

Comment: For that you might find [here](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP1/HDP-1.2.2/bk_installing_manually_book/content/rmp-chap14-2-3-5.html) what you need.

Comment: I tried ./hive -e 'SHOW TABLES'
It returns OK